# How can I provide a default implementation of IntoIterator for a trait?

Tags: rust, traits

I have the following trait and an iterator for it:

```rust
pub trait Stack<'a> {
    type Item;

    fn empty() -> Self;
    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool;
    fn cons(&'a self, val: &'a Self::Item) -> Self;
    fn head(&self) -> &Self::Item;
    fn tail(&self) -> &Self;
}

pub struct StackIter<'a, TStack: Stack<'a>> {
    stack: &'a TStack,
}

impl<'a, TStack: Stack<'a>> Iterator for StackIter<'a, TStack> {
    type Item = &'a TStack::Item;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.stack.is_empty() {
            Option::None
        } else {
            let val = self.stack.head();
            self.stack = self.stack.tail();
            Option::Some(val)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to define a default implementation of `IntoIterator` for the `Stack` trait, so I tried this:

```rust
pub trait Stack<'a>: IntoIterator {
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

This won't work since we can't define a default value for the type `IntoIterator::IntoIter`.

I tried providing an implementation outside of `Stack`:

```rust
impl<'a, TStack: Stack<'a>> IntoIterator for &'a TStack {
    type Item = &'a TStack::Item;
    type IntoIter = StackIter<'a, TStack>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        StackIter { stack: self }
    }
}
```

But then I get the following errors:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `std::iter::IntoIterator` for type `&_`:
  --> src/lib.rs:28:1
   |
28 | impl<'a, TStack: Stack<'a>> IntoIterator for &'a TStack {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
           - impl<I> std::iter::IntoIterator for I
             where I: std::iter::Iterator;
   = note: downstream crates may implement trait `std::iter::Iterator` for type `&_`

error[E0210]: type parameter `TStack` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<TStack>`)
  --> src/lib.rs:28:1
   |
28 | impl<'a, TStack: Stack<'a>> IntoIterator for &'a TStack {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type parameter `TStack` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
   |
   = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter
```

Comment: Error makes sense because for all `Iterator`s there is an `IntoIter` implementation in core, why do you want to implement your own ?, actually you are doing exactly the same implementation in core implementation.

Comment: @ÖmerErden
I don't want to implement it for the StackIter. I want to implement it for the Stack (which is not necessarily an Iterator)

Comment: The error is saying that some implementations of Stack might also implement Iterator. Fine, but I want to provide an implementation for those that don't.

Comment: You can't. This is the orphan rule - you cannot implement a trait from another crate for type that are also in another crate. A generic type parameter could be any type, including those in other crates, so you cannot write a blanket impl like that.